# Prevent DOM refresh in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dom

I'm trying to implement an animated carousel, with code like this:

```
<template>
<div v-for="(slides, id)" v-if="id > middle_id - 2 || id < middle_id + 2">
<div :class="'slide'+id"><slide :key="id" :slide-data="slide" /></div>
</div>
</template>
```

the number of slides is variable, but only the middle 5 are displayed. The animations just use css animation, based on the slide number.

this works fine if I add or remove slides one at a time - the existing dom elements don't change and only a new slide is added. But if I add a slide to the end and remove one from the start simultaneously, vue appears to re-render all of the dom elements in the sliding window.

is there a way to ensure that during this operation, the 3 middle slides that haven't changed are not updated in the dom?

Comment: Could you create a fiddle to show your problem?

Comment: Add a `key`, not the index, to your `v-for`.

Answer (score 0):

### Vue 3.2+

In Vue versions 3.2 and up, this can be done with `v-memo`

> ```
> <div v-memo="[valueA, valueB]">
>   ...
> </div>
> ```
>
> **When the component re-renders, if both valueA and valueB remain the same, all updates for this  and its children will be skipped.** In fact, even the Virtual DOM VNode creation will also be skipped since the memoized copy of the sub-tree can be reused.

https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-directives.html#v-memo

Comment: Something like this is just what I need but for Vue 2. Is there a solution for this in the latest Vue 2.x? Can't upgrade to Vue 3 yet on huge project. Need to conditionally stop updates like v-memo does.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue while using Vue to implement carousel texts, and I found a solution to address it effectively.

Vue employs certain heuristics within its source code that determine whether or not to recycle DOM elements in different scenarios. Specifically, Vue does not recycle DOM elements in cases where

- a single node is removed, or
- a single node is added, or
- the attributes of a node are modified.

In your case, the problem arises when you add and remove slides in a single step. When you add a slide and then remove another one in the next step, Vue does not trigger a rerendering of the DOM elements.

Vue updates the DOM **asynchronously**, which means that multiple modification to the data will be packed into one, and DOM will be updated only once. To ensure that the addition and removal of slides are treated as separate steps, I discovered that utilizing `await Vue.nextTick()` (or `await this.$nextTick()`) is an effective approach. `await Vue.nextTick()` means never execute the code below that line until DOM is updated.

To implement this solution, you can follow the example code provided below:

```js
async function updateSlides() {
    // Add a new slide to the array
    this.arr.push({ ... })

    // Wait for the DOM update, ensuring separate steps
    await this.$nextTick()

    // Remove the first slide from the array
    this.arr.splice(0, 1)
}
```

By following this approach, you should achieve the desired outcome and resolve the issue effectively.